# adding " in abbrev for emacs

Tags: emacs

How can I add a `"` in abbrev mode.

`("stdce" "std::cout << " "<< std::endl;")`

The " is not added but the line finishes after that 
and i tried `/"` `\"` but that wont work

Comment: how do i close the question ?

Answer (score 0):

never mind, 
it worked.

I used `\"` and it worked fine. May be I didn't upload it when I tried before.